# How to link msvcrt.lib?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can I link `msvcrt.lib` with delphi? I am trying to link a `.obj` file with Delphi. And it works but it has way too many missing dependencies.

```
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__purecall'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??2@YAPAXI@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??3@YAXPAX@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_atexit'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp___hypot'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp__memchr'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp__memmove'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??_Eerror_category@std@@UAEPAXI@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??_E_Generic_error_category@std@@UAEPAXI@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??_E_Iostream_error_category@std@@UAEPAXI@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??_E_System_error_category@std@@UAEPAXI@Z'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '@__security_check_cookie@4'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__CxxThrowException@8'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '___CxxFrameHandler3'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '??_7type_info@@6B@'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '___security_cookie'
[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(24): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__fltused'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot link `.lib` files to Delphi. If you link `.obj` files then you must supply any missing functions by either:

1. Linking a `.obj` file that defines the function, or
2. Implementing the function in Delphi and making it visible to the unit that links the other `.obj` files.

A bigger problem is that you are attempting to link a C++ object and to the very best of my knowledge that is not viable. If that's really what you need to do, then you will have to compile it to a DLL and link it that way.

Comment: You can wrap the functions in extern "C" which is what I have done.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your code is C++. That just changes the linkage. You have effectively no hope of success here, in my view. Compile this code into a DLL and link it that way.

Comment: Can string types be used from Delphi to C++ DLL?

Comment: Not Delphi strings or C++ strings. You need to use C strings. Pointer to null-terminated arrays of characters.

Comment: Yes but what if i want to use the DLL function with Unicode String? :)

Comment: It's exactly the same. Pointer to null-terminated arrays of characters. Either 8 bit UTF-8 characters, or 16 bit UTF-16 characters or 32 bit UTF-32 characters.

Comment: Not really. You need to caller to allocate a modifiable buffer. The callee can then copy into it. See the windows api for examples.